# Best practice for working on a local branch+PR based off another local branch+PR

Tags: git, github

I am trying to figure out the best workflow for working with multiple branches, and PRs which may be based off of each other.  I just want to know what are the best practices, specifically around rebasing in this case so that I don't get git into a bad state. Here is more or less what I am doing so far, with a few of the scenarios described. Please let me know what would be a better practice here:

I work with github, having an origin master remote repo on github, my own user remote repo as well. I push to my user remote repo and make PRs into the origin master remote repo.

```
 git checkout master
 git checkout -b branch_first
 .. do some work ...
 git commit
 git push remote
 # Make a PR on github for branch_first, to merge it into the origin master branch

 # While I wait for comments/review on branch_first, start to 
 # Work on branch_second
 git checkout -b branch_second  # This branch is based off first
 .. do some work ...
 git commit
 git push remote
 # Make a PR on github for branch_second, to merge it into the origin master branch

 # Got some review comments, checkout branch_first and make some changes
 git checkout branch_first
 .. do some work ...
 git commit
 git push remote # Possibly repeat this, or ask the committer to merge when done.
```

Now this seems to mostly work, however I seem to get myself into bad states often when rebasing.

Occasionally, you need to squash fixup commits to keep the PR clean and easy to review. So I run something like this on say branch_second.

```
rebase -i HEAD~10
# change commits to fixup or squash and save.
```

Doing this I have encountered weird behaviours, needing to fix merge conflicts with files I haven't edited for example. I am told by a peer that this can potentially take all 10 previous commits and find a common ancestor to move the branch_second pointer, causing weird issues like this.

Occasionally, I need to get the code files I changed during the branch_first code review into branch_second

```
rebase branch_first
```

From what I understand, this may not work properly all the time? I think sometimes this is getting me into a bad state. I have been told by some peers that this might be more appropriate to run on branch_second

```
git rebase --onto master branch_first branch_second
```

Occasionally, I need to get files from origin master again. So I run this on branch_first or branch_second.

```
git fetch origin master
git rebase origin/master
```

Sometimes when I am running rebase commands, I lose the ancestry, I have the commits I want mostly, but I don't see branch_first in the git log history for the commits I expect.

Comment: Could you give some more details about `rebase branch_first` getting you into a bad state? This is a pretty common git workflow and should not be causing any nasty surprises.

Comment: Maybe that one is not causing issues specifically, I was just trying to write up the whole workflow of what I was doing.

I think maybe I ran into this issue when I tried to
rebase branch_second     while working on branch_first. I was hoping that this would be possible as well. In the case that you decide you want to send out a PR for branch_second before branch_first. I think this is possible, though I am not sure the implications.

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase -i HEAD~10` when on branch_second will cause branch_first and branch_second to diverge if HEAD~10 is older than the two branches' common ancestor. This can cause you not to see branch_first in branch_second's commit history. It's a better idea to only ever rebase branch_second onto branch_first.

`rebase branch_first` when on branch_second, to get commits from your branch_first PR into branch_second, is a pretty common workflow and should not really be causing any weird errors.

`git rebase origin/master` when on branch_second basically makes copies (with different commit IDs) of all commits on branch_second up to the common ancestor of branch_second and origin/master. Since branch_first is still associated with the old commits (that were just copied), it won't show up when looking at the history of branch_second after this rebase.

I would suggest reading [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) article to build more intuition for what `git rebase` does.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try, follow this pattern. If I have more issues I hope I can document more specifically what happens